# standard/best practise for images as links?

Tags: html

Should i be doing `a tags` with background images? (allows img sprites)

or `a tags` containing `img tags`?

I'm thinking semantics and transparency for search engines,

is there a norm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have `<a>` tags containing `<img>` tags.
Make sure to include meaningful `alt` attributes in your `<img>` tags.